# Android: work with Parse database for an IncrementKey column at Parse

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, cloud, auto-increment

I am working on a Android app and is using Parse Database, and would like to add a  `IncrementKey` function such that when a new image is added to the database, the image_id column would increase itself by 1.

Reference: https://www.parse.com/questions/incrementkey

### Question:

However, googled for a long while, there are no explicit example to show how to get it work... it involves cloud code at parse. Would there be any hints on how could that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Cloud code is easy to implement. What's the issue ?

Comment: I totally have no knowledge on that...do you have some examples?

Comment: They have a guide that will help you with it. It is basically JavaScript code. You can get tons of tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a beforeSave trigger for `Image` (replace where relevant, I've assumed this is your Class that holds the images and counter column - these are properties of the same Object)

file: `./cloud_code/cloud/main.js` or a filepath `require`d by *main.js*

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Image", function(request, response) {

    //check if this is a new or existing Image
    if (!request.object.isNew()) {
          //image exists, save as normal
          response.success();
    } else { 

        //find the last image saved
        var checkImage = Parse.Object.extend("Image");
        var imagesQuery = new Parse.Query(checkImage);
        imagesQuery.select("image_id"); //save memory by only requesting image_id
        imagesQuery.descending("image_id"); //sort, make sure image_id is a Number

        imagesQuery.first().then(
            function(lastImage) {
                //increase the id by 1
                var newId = lastImage.get("image_id") + 1;

                //save the current object with the new id
                request.object.set("image_id", newId); 
                response.success(); //this saves your request.object
            }, 
            function (error)
                response.error(error);
            }
        );

    }

});
```

#### Resources

- Cloud code guide: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide
- Cloud code beforeSave modify: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modifying-objects-on-save
- Retrieving objects: https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving
- Increment (updating an existing field): https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-counters
- See also [Parse cloudcode beforeSave obtain pre-updated object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082262/parse-cloudcode-beforesave-obtain-pre-updated-object) (the other way around)

Read the Cloud code guide to learn how to e.g. install the CLI tools to deploy your Cloud Code and check the Cloud logs for debugging.

- Disclaimer: code above is untested but based on working functions

**Note:** use `isNew()` in a `beforeSave` handler, `existed` in an `afterSave` handler. There's a reported bug for `existed` in Parse Cloud Code versions 1.6.* - see [Parse request.object.existed() return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931357/parse-request-object-existed-return-false)

Comment: Please note a parse object has a unique id with `objectId` or `image.id`. Cloud code functions save when you call `reponse.success`, normal controllers should use `imageCounts.save();` You can increment an *existing* Number field with `imageCounts.increment("image_count")`