# Parse request.object.existed() return false

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have problem with parse. I wrote cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
  var user = request.object;
  if( !user.existed() ) {
      //all the times !user.existed() is true when I save user object
      //also in signup is true
  }

})
```

how can I make the inside if block run only if the user is new user?

Comment: What is `Parse.User` ?

Comment: this is parse user obejct

Comment: Ok I found that this is a bug
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1675561372679121/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be a Parse bug as of the latest Parse Javascript SDK (1.6.7).

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1675561372679121/

A quick work around (courtesy of Andrei Patru in the above thread):

```
var createdAt = request.object.get("createdAt");
var updatedAt = request.object.get("updatedAt");
var objectExisted = (createdAt.getTime() != updatedAt.getTime());
```

Just tested it and it works.

Comment: According to the bug report comments and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/existed/parse-developers/dFCUAZnYCiI/qrpl6kgVAgAJ this also affects other 1.6.* releases - I'm on 1.4.2 and not affected, an alternative is to fall back to 1.5.0