# Clone Parse Server object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a Parse object (well, an array of parse objects). I want to make a clone of the objects but everything I try fails...in that changing the original object attributes also changes the clone's corresponding attribute. I have tried using Parse.Object.clone(), creating new array of objects, changing to JSON and then doing a deep clone but nothing works. After some research I came across [this](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_disableSingleInstance) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960992/487873) but this does offer a real solution.

Is there no good way to clone Parse objects and have the attributes be completely separate??

I want to essentially have a 'cancel' changes button which would revert to the cloned versions and not save.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Parse.Object.clone` returns a shallow copy. For a deep copy (completely independant objects) I've written and used this code:

```
var originalObject = ...
var objectJSON = originalObject.toJSON();
delete objectJSON.objectId; // force it to be a new DB object if you save it
var twin = new Parse.Object( object.className );
twin.set( objectJSON );
```

In my opinion a Parse.Object.deepClone method would be nice...

Comment: Thanks, changing the ID was the key to get this to work. I ended up adding a prefix to the ID to clone and then remove the ID if I need to revert to the cloned version.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening with Parse.Object.clone()? That seems like it should be what you want.

the iOS (and likely the android) SDK has a revert method on objects to reset to the last time it was saved / fetched.

Keep in mind that for objects in javascript, passing them into functions treats them as pass by reference, more or less, so changes within a function will change the object passed in. Sometimes useful and sometimes annoying.

If Parse.Object.clone() isn't working, My next suggestion, while annoying, would be to create a new object shell and fetch it / query for the object if you need includes when you need to "reset" the data.

Comment: I did a clone and then manipulated the original object and found that the clone had changed too!! From what I read, if objects have the same id then parse treats the attributes as common. I guess querying is the way to go... :(