# PARSE check original object on BeforeSave

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-javascript-sdk

I need to check the original object on before save to see what value has changed. currently i have this:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Stats", function(request, response) {
if (!request.object.isNew()){
        var query = new Parse.Query("Stats");
        query.get(request.object.id, { 
            success: function(oldObject) {
            alert('OLD:' + oldObject.get("Score") + "new:" + request.object.get("Score"));
                /*Do My Stuff Here*/
                response.success(); 
            },
            error: function(oldObject, error) {
                response.error(error.message);
            }
        });
    }else{
        response.success();
    }

});
```

The problem is that `oldObject` is equal to `request.object`.

Also the alert result is this: `OLD:10 new:10`, but the real old score was `5`. Also according to the before save input log the original is really `5`.

Any ideia what i am doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is the before save log.

```
before_save triggered for Stats as master:
Input: {"original":{"achievements":[],"Score":"100"updatedAt":"2015-11-02T10:09:24.170Z"},"update":{"Score":"110"}}
Result: Update changed to {"Score":"110"}
```

Edit2:
Is there any way to get the dirty value?

```
console.log("dirty: "+ request.object.dirty("score"));
I2015-11-03T14:23:12.198Z]dirty: true
```

Comment: Did you check the to see if your Score field is dirty like `request.object.dirty("Score")` ?

Comment: Both `request.object.dirtyKeys` and `request.object.dirty("Score")` return `undefined`

Comment: Something must be wrong because if you are updating fields, you should see them flagged as dirty. Btw how does Javascript `alert` function work on Cloud ??

Comment: @MoNazemi [this](http://s2.postimg.org/q74o9gd15/Screen_Shot_2015_11_02_at_12_52_44.png) is how `alert` looks like

Comment: If there are no dirty fields your request is not going to update anything, can you show what your update request looks like and how you are doing it ?

Comment: @MoNazemi added the `before save` log.

Comment: Have you tried calling `request.object.dirty("Score")` *before* the query?

Comment: `request.object.dirty("score")` returns `true`. But how do i get the dirt `dirty` value?

Comment: My guess is that querying for that object somehow updates all "instances" of that object in the current scope, and that's way dirty() works only if called *before*. As to how to get the old score, I don't know. You could create another field, "oldScore", and mantain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official way to know if a field was modified is to call `dirty()`.

My guess is that querying for that particular object somehow updates all "instances" of that object in the current scope, and that's way `dirty()` works only if called *before* the query.

An option to get both the old and the new value is to mantain it in a separate field. For example, from your client you could call (pseudocoding, but you get the point):

```
// OldScore here is 0
statObject.put("Score") = 100;
statObject.saveInBackground();
```

Then in Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Stats", function(request, response) {

    var stat = request.object;
    if (!stat.isNew()){
        if (stat.dirty("Score")) {
            var newValue = stat.get("Score") // 100
            var oldValue = stat.get("OldScore") // 0

            // Do other stuff here

            stat.put("OldScore", newValue);
            response.success();

        } else {
            response.success();
        }
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

However the issue you are describing is somewhat strange. Maybe you could try with the `fetch()` command; it should return the old value. However it will invalidate every other dirty field.

Comment: I did't wanted to duplicate the fields, and since the `before save` log has the original value i was wondering if there was any way to get it directly. If there no other way to achieve this i will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: There is no API to get it directly, see the [answer here](https://parse.com/questions/cloudcode-haschanged-and-previous), but other guys here on SO used your exact method and it worked, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082262/parse-cloudcode-beforesave-obtain-pre-updated-object) for example. I don't know why it wouldn't work with you, maybe something changed in the SDK lately.

Comment: I got my code from that post. Also, since that code did not work anymore i was wondering that was changed in any way.