# How to use DirtyKeys to know if "email" field in PFUser has been modified?

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code, mailgun, email-verification

I'm using cloudcode of Parse-Server and mailgun to send email-verification Code to users that signup or change their email.

**The BeforeSave Method :**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {


    var verificationCode = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);

    var text = "Hi ... this is a verification code:" + verificationCode;


    var data = {
      from: 'WBP Team <info@test.eu>',
      to: request.object.get("email"),
      subject: 'Please verify your e-mail for you Account',
      text: text
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {

      if (error) {

            response.error("Email not sent..."+error);

      }else{

            var user = Parse.User.current();
            user.set("emailVerificationCode", verificationCode);
            user.save();

            response.success("Email Sent");
      }

      console.log(body);
    });



});
```

Now the email is sent everytime the user modify any filed. But I would like to use the method only when the user change the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26726880/5471218): you just check if `request.object.dirtyKeys()` contains `"email"`; if this is the case, the email property was changed, and you can send your verification.

Note that this check also catches the first saving (i.e. creation) of a user; if you want to avoid sending a mail then, you can use `request.object.isNew()` to find out if the operation is a create or an update.